# How to decode MPA audio format using Mediacodec in android

Tags: android, rtsp, android-mediacodec, live555

My app plays RTSP streams using Live555 rtsp client.  The testing stream is created by VLC Player (H264 + MP3 (TS)).  The H264 video played well.  But the audio (MPA format) not played and application crashes.  I am using separate Mediacodec class for decoding Video and Audio.  I used mime type "audio/mpeg" for decoding the audio. How can i successfully play audio.

**Audio Decoder Class**

```
public class ADecoder extends Thread {

    private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = ADecoder.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String AUDIO_FORMAT = "audio/mpeg";
    private static final long mTimeoutUs = 10000l;

    private MediaCodec mMediaCodec;
    volatile boolean m_bConfigured;
    volatile boolean m_bRunning;
    long startMs;
    Bitmap lastimage = null;
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = null;
    private AudioTrack audioTrack;

    public ADecoder() {
    }

    public void decode(byte[] encodedData) {
        if(!m_bConfigured) {
            Configure(encodedData);
        }
        if(m_bConfigured) {
            decodeData(encodedData);
        }
    }

    public void Start() {
        if(m_bRunning)
            return;
        m_bRunning = true;
        start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if(!m_bRunning)
            return;
        m_bRunning = false;
    }

    private void _Stop(){
        if( mMediaCodec != null ) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Trying to Stop & Release Audio Decoder");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
            }
            mMediaCodec.stop();
            mMediaCodec.release();
        }

        if( audioTrack != null ){
            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
        }
    }

    private void Configure( byte[] csd0) {
        try {
            if (m_bConfigured) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Audio Decoder is already configured");
                return;
            }

            MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(AUDIO_FORMAT, 44100, 2);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x12};
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
            format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", bb);

            try {
                mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(AUDIO_FORMAT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to create Audio Decodec: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mMediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, 0);
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio Decoder configured.");

            mMediaCodec.start();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Audio Decoder initialized.");

            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    44100,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            m_bConfigured = true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void decodeData(byte[] data) {
        try {
            if (!m_bConfigured) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Audio Decoder is not configured yet.");
                return;
            }
            int inIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(mTimeoutUs);
            if (inIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    buffer = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers()[inIndex];
                    buffer.clear();
                } else {
                    buffer = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                }
                if (buffer != null) {
                    buffer.put(data);
                    long presentationTimeUs = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs;
                    mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, data.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(m_bRunning) {
                if(m_bConfigured) {
                    outputBuffers = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
                    MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                    int outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, mTimeoutUs);
                    if(outIndex >= 0) {
                        ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                        byte[] decoded_chunk = new byte[info.size];
                        buffer.get(decoded_chunk); // Read the buffer all at once
                        buffer.clear();
                        audioTrack.write(decoded_chunk, info.offset, info.offset + info.size);
                        mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                    } else {
                        if( outIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED ){
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Info output buffers changed");
                        } else if( outIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED ){
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "New format " + mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat());
                        } else if( outIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED ){
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            _Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

**App Crash Details**

```
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.mp3.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001)
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
I/MediaCodec: name=video/avc isType=true encoder=false
I/MediaCodec: (0x94673800) init name(video/avc) isType(1) encoder(0)
I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2640)
W/System.err:     at com.mtxlabs.ipcamera.video.ADecoder.run(ADecoder.java:154)
```

**Audio Decoder Init debugger output**

```
2019-02-25 16:30:41.171  I/MediaCodec: name=audio/mpeg isType=true encoder=false
2019-02-25 16:30:41.172  I/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) init name(audio/mpeg) isType(1) encoder(0)
2019-02-25 16:30:41.174  I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
2019-02-25 16:30:41.175  I/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) Component Allocated (OMX.google.mp3.decoder)
2019-02-25 16:30:41.176  I/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) configure surface(0x0) crypto(0x0) flags(0)
2019-02-25 16:30:41.176  D/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) configure format: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
          int32_t sample-rate = 44100
          string mime = "audio/mpeg"
          int32_t channel-count = 2
          Buffer csd-0 = {
            00000000:  12 12                                             ..
          }
        }

2019-02-25 16:30:41.178  I/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) start
2019-02-25 16:30:41.179  D/CameraLive: #24 audio/MPA 417 bytes
2019-02-25 16:30:41.184  D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x9330a008 for 448x336, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
2019-02-25 16:30:41.185  I/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) kWhatStartCompleted
2019-02-25 16:30:41.187  D/ADecoder: Audio Decoder initialized.
2019-02-25 16:30:41.188  D/MediaCodec: (0xa616d2c0) [OMX.google.mp3.decoder] output format changed to: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
          string mime = "audio/raw"
          int32_t channel-count = 2
          int32_t sample-rate = 44100
          int32_t pcm-encoding = 2
        }
2019-02-25 16:30:41.190  D/MediaCodec: (0xa616d040) kWhatOutputBuffersChanged
2019-02-25 16:30:41.193  D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
```

Comment: With this little information no one can help you. Why is the App crashing? How do you initialize the decoder? Etc. Post a stacktrace and/or some code.

Comment: @ChrisBe I upaded the question with details

Comment: Can you add the debugger output of the codec Initialization? The app crashes because initialization of the decoder failed but you try to poll the codec. I'm not very familiar with MP3 but do you need the `0x12 0x12` CSD

Comment: Error Code `0x80001001` seems to be `OMX_ErrorUndefined`

Comment: @ChrisBe debugger output is added

Comment: I can't find a obvious mistake here. Are you running this on an Emulator? If so, have you tried to run this on a physical device?

Comment: I am running on Moto G (5S) Plus Android 8.1.0

Comment: What is the `csd-0`, `0x12 0x12` supposed to mean, can't find a reference to mp3 csd's. Have you tried without?

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: @artman Sorry bro. I dropped the project